# Hide iOS NavigationBar on one ViewController - weird animation happening

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a standard UINavigationController for an iOS application in Swift 5 in which I'd like to hide the Navigation Bar on the **first** ViewController in the stack.

My storyboard is essentially:

UINavigationController -> ViewControllerA -> ViewControllerB

with simple Show segues.

In **ViewControllerA** I put the following:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
```

In **ViewControllerB** I put the following:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}
```

But in the simulator the transition from A->B presents this weird, like, "scooping" animation and I cannot figure out how to get rid of it.

Thoughts?  Thank you in advance!

[image: Odd animation in ViewController transition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another method for hiding the navigation bar where you can set 'animated' to false which might help you.

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```